# docplex issue : TypeError: Cannot convert linear constraint to a boolean value: 0 <= 1

Tags: python, docplex

Issue at binary constraint in docplex

Binary constraint is initialised as  if i am trying to initialise it directly without list binary variable is consisting of default value and i am not able to clear it
[Binary constraint is initialised as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P61bJ.png)

Constraints are given as

[Binay Constraint are given as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcD4R.png)

Error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMQGE.png)

Please help me in finding
(i)what is the mistake i have done
(ii)how can i correct it

Answer (score 0):

You should use a range instead.

Let me start from the [zoo example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoo.py)

And suppose you want to have nbbus40 between 4 and 5 you can write:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')

#mdl.add_constraint(4<=nbbus40<=5)
mdl.add_range(4, nbbus40, 5)

mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve(log_output=True,)

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```